# Launcher Activity Not getting called on marshmallow Android

Tags: android, android-activity, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have developed an application 6 months back for target version 22.

**build.Gradle**

```
android {

     compileSdkVersion 22
     buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"

   defaultConfig {
     applicationId "com.sample.mobile.test"
     minSdkVersion 17
     targetSdkVersion 22
     versionCode 1
     versionName "2.3"
     multiDexEnabled true
   }
}
```

so now when i am trying to run the application on marshmallow by just changing the

`compileSdkVersion 23`

`targetSdkVersion 23`

it is not calling the launcher activity of an application and also the strange thing is, it is not throwing any error.
I am not getting where the problem is, so please help me to resolve this issue,
Thanks in advance.

Comment: post your manifest file also @Yash

Comment: @yash please check using debugger or check any messages in Logcat

Comment: Also check your app permissions. If it stopped working on Android 6.0 then it's possible that it's due to new permissions model.

Comment: check runtime permission